# Paypal Standard API, going from UK to US

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

The company that I work for uses a **Paypal Standard API and IPN API** in the **UK** and is moving to the **US** (so basically it has a US Paypal account), Are there any specific changes between the APIs for these two different regions? or should the code work for both (provided that they change their account information).

Sorry if this is some sort of duplicate question, but the documentations in the Paypal site are just awful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd be happy to receive any comments on how you'd like to see the documentation improved. Email address is in my profile here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coding for PayPal Standard and IPN should be the same between UK and US.